# Robocorp - Trigger process GitHub Action not working

Tags: bots, github-actions, robotframework, rpa

This is a clone of [my post in the Robocorp forum](https://forum.robocorp.com/t/trigger-process-github-action-not-working/2364).

I’m trying to get the trigger process github action to work, but I’m getting:

```
Error: Failed to start process - {"error":{"code":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","subCode":"","message":"Not authorized to read process !"}}
```

The above link says the API key should have the `trigger_processes` permission and the action’s repo says it should have the `read_runs` and `trigger_processes` permissions. In any case, the API key [those 2 permissions, as well as read_processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qR6o.png).

I can see that the key is being used, and there is only one .github/workflow file. The workflow is basically the same as the one in the tutorial but here it is for completeness:

```
name: Trigger a process in Control Room

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  run-process:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Trigger process
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Control Room process run
        uses: robocorp/action-trigger-process@v1
        with:
          api-key: ${{ secrets.ROBOCORP_WORKSPACE_KEY_TRIGGER }}
          workspace-id: ${{ secrets.ROBOCORP_WORKSPACE_ID }}
          process-id: ${{ secrets.ROBOCORP_PROCESS_ID }}
          payload: '{"foo":"bar"}'
          await-complete: true
```

I’m also getting a warning (`Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: robocorp/action-trigger-process@v1`) but I don’t imagine that’s the issue.

What am I missing?

Thanks

I followed the tutorial, even added all of the permissions to the API key. I removed the other workflow .yml to help isolate any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems it's working now. I'm guessing I hadn't correctly set the `env.json` or used the correct access credentials. Once I reset the access credentials and set up a correct sequence of steps in my github actions workflow, this action worked fine.